# How to play on Minecraft Servers on different versions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have recently bought and installed Minecraft Java Edition Version 1.17, and today decided to play Hypixel, but I have noticed that on the Hypixel website, it says that the best version to play is 1.8, since if you play on version 1.11 or later, the game mechanics will be different. And, I have noticed this after I joined the server.

So, is it possible to make the game mechanics in Minecraft Servers work on all versions?

Comment: Generally whenever a server offers multiple versions, use the oldest ones. Is there a specific reason you wanna use this version or is it just something you'd prefer?

Comment: as another note, making the mechanics work on multiple versions is a fully serverside endeavor. and minecraft 1.17 hasnt been released, but i cant edit that.

Answer (score 2):

**No, this is difficult to do.** Every version of Minecraft will run slightly different, and some very different compared to other versions. If you want to play with the most correct mechanics in that specific server, you should use the optimal version that Hypixel (or any server) specifies, otherwise your gameplay might be effected negatively. In fact, some servers won't even allow you to join unless you use their recommended version of Minecraft.

As another note, it is a fully serverside choice, meaning you cannot do anything about a server not supporting a version.

Comment: "Every version of Minecraft will run substantially different compared to other versions." not every version, many are very similar.

Comment: @Topcode I think we get what he is trying to say basically, though that is not exactly correct, but we get what he is trying to convey right?

Comment: @RyugaGod yeah, i know. but many servers have overcome the challenge (like hypixel) and allow basically any version to join. and its not a challenge to allow crossplay between minor updates, like 1.16.4 and 1.16.5

Comment: @Topcode My bad. That was a typo. Most servers will allow a transition between "hotfix updates" such as what you stated.

Comment: Do downvoters have reasons they wanna share? I don't really see a reason to downvote this

Answer (score -1):

You bought Minecraft Java Edition, period. You installed the version 1.17. But you have access to almost all versions, dating back to 1.0 and Beta. All you have to do is to open the Launcher, pick the 'Installations' tab, 'New installation' and pick whichever version you want from the drop-down menu. 'Create', return to the 'Play' tab and pick the new installation from the drop-down left from the 'play' button, and you'll play that version in a moment.

It takes a bit more work to have different installations differing with mods, if you install any, and there are serious issues with playing single player worlds on mismatching versions but that doesn't concern you now. You can play on Hypixel as the server authors intended.

In particular, Hypixel is unusual to even allow multiple versions (1.8 - 1.16.5) - most servers require you use installation that matches the version perfectly, and won't allow you to log in with a different one. So in short, you can't make the server support all versions, but there is absolutely no need for that - it's trivial to get an installation matching the server's version.

Comment: @Penguin I'm not sure what you're disagreeing with. You buy JE, download the newest Launcher. with 6 clicks create a 1.8 installation and play on Hypixel using your new 1.8 installation which runs exactly the same as every 1.8 Minecraft since the day 1.8 was released. The fact it runs under a 1.16 Launcher doesn't change the game behavior the least bit. Minecraft makes switching client versions exceptionally easy, so OP essentially asked an XY question, "how to make server support my current client", the answer is "don't, get a client matching the server, it's trivial!"

Comment: i disagree that "Hypixel is unusual to even allow multiple versions" almost every *major* server supports multiple versions, ones that dont support multiple versions cant get as popular. You also say "there is absolutely no need for that" i disagree, there is absolutely a need to support the newest versions, as that is what new players will use. ""how to make server support my current client", the answer is "don't, get a client matching the server, it's trivial!"" thats not an answer at all, you are not answering the users question.

Comment: @Topcode It's a bit like answering "I just earned $1000 (in $10-$50 notes). I just paid for my shoppings in a Russian warehouse, but I got much less than my money's worth and they said I should exchange the money to Rubles. How do I make shops (worldwide) accept my US dollar notes as payment, for or near the full value?"

Comment: @SF. nvm then i thought you were saying that playing in 1.8 and 1.16 doesnt make a difference. The statement i was combatting "it's trivial to get an installation matching the server's version" is confusing